# EntityFramework.Extended Update - Trying to set one column to another

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using the [EntityFramework.Extended](http://www.loresoft.com/projects/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries/default.aspx) library to try to bulk update a table. It works great if the value I'm assigning is a constant but when I try to assign one column to another it throws an exception. For example (this is contrived just to get the idea across)

```
// This works fine    
Update<Client>( c => c.Active, c => new Client() { DatabaseId = 100 } );

// This throws an exception
Update<Client>( c => c.Active, c => new Client() { DatabaseId = c.ClientId } );
```

The exception that gets thrown is

*System.InvalidOperationException, variable 'c' of type 'Client' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined*

Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: It is open source project. You can check the source code if this kind of operation is even supported.

Comment: I've looked at the source. It contains a branch for a non-constant assignment but that's what's blowing up. What I was wondering was whether I'm just doing something wrong in how I'm forming the query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Update<Client>( c => c.Active, nc => new Client() { DatabaseId = c.ClientId } );
```